# Can MSTest ignore the nested exceptions and only test against the last?

Tags: mstest

Imagine that you have a function that checks if the provided string value is empty like below:

```
string IsNotEmpty(string value)
{
    if (!string.IsEmpty(value)) return value
    else throw new Exception("Value is empty");
}
```

Also imagine that we have many other parts of our code that call this generic function to check if there is a value and if not throw a more specific exception than the generic one. As an example i will provide the below code:

```
string CheckEmail(string email)
{
    try
    {
        return IsNotEmpty(email);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new **EmptyEmailException**("Please provide your email");
    }
}
```

Now i want to write a MSTest for the CheckEmail function that expects an exception of type **EmptyEmailException** to be thrown. But unfortunately the test captures only the generic **Exception** from IsNotEmpty function, it stops execution and the code never tests the second exception.

Things i have done without any success:

1. I wrote my test with ExpectedException attribute.
2. I wrote my test
   with Assert.ThrowsException.
3. I updated the exception settings in VS
   to not brake on exceptions of type Exception, just to see if that
   will resolve my issue.

No matter what i do MSTest always reports the first exception and of course my test fails. Below is my current test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void When_Validating_SignInRequest_And_Email_IsEmpty_Raise_EmptyEmailException()
{
    var ex = Assert.ThrowsException<EmptyEmailException>(
                () => CheckEmail(string.Empty)
            );
}
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine on my end:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class EmptyEmailException : Exception
    {
        public EmptyEmailException(string message) : base(message)
        { }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public static string IsNotEmpty(string value)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return value;
            else
                throw new Exception("Value is empty");
        }

        public static string CheckEmail(string email)
        {
            try
            {
                return IsNotEmpty(email);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new EmptyEmailException("Please provide your email");
            }
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.ThrowsException<EmptyEmailException>(() => MyClass.CheckEmail(string.Empty));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Peska. After your code example, you confirmed to me that perhaps the problem is somewhere else, so i tested the test in a different VS installation and it passed. I am sure now, that it has something to to with my VS installation settings. My first stop will be in the Exception Settings. Thank you again.